# Linking to a file in a folder by clicking on an image

Tags: html, image, file, hyperlink

Basically I am trying to link to 2 local files that are webpages that are uploaded on the same host as the webpage being browsed. It's supposed to happen by clicking on one of these two images - [Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ke7Uw.jpg). What am I doing wrong? I cannot click on the images to open the file in a new tab.

Here are my folders - [Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKi4A.jpg)

This is the code -

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <a href="MyIndia/index.html" target="_blank"><img src="images/slide3/MyIndia.png" data-stellar-ratio="1.8" data-stellar-vertical-offset="-200" alt=""></a>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <a href="PizzaCat/index.html" target="_blank"><img src="images/slide3/PizzaCat.png" data-stellar-ratio="1.8" data-stellar-vertical-offset="-35" alt=""></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Are both the "MyIndia" and "PizzaCat" folders in the root directory of the file that is linking to them?

Comment: Added a picture of my folders to the main post

Comment: I'm asssuming the code above is in index.html? Try adding a forward slash in front of the folder names, i.e. "/MyIndia/index.html" and "/PizzaCat/index.html"

Comment: @user13286 didn't help

Comment: Do you want the images to be opened? Or the index page?

Comment: The index pages of past projects that I've made. It should open them in a new tab and they will be uploaded on the same server as the index file

Comment: What is the filename then?

Comment: @rubo77 both files are index.html but they are in different folders

Comment: then the PizzaCat link should work like you have it now

Comment: Does the index page in the pizza cat folder work on its own? Can you post the full URL as an example here?

Comment: @rubo77 - yes , both are pages on their own , look at the pizza cat folder for example http://i.imgur.com/DoZNv26.jpg

Comment: I added details to my answer below, please check all of these. And please tell us, which webserver you are using and where you want to upload it to. And if it is already visible in the net somewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code that should work:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<a href="PizzaCat/index.html" target="_blank"><img src="images/slide3/MyIndia.png" data-stellar-ratio="1.8" data-stellar-vertical-offset="-200" alt=""></a>
</div>
...
```

And be sure of these details:

- all files online should be readable by Apache (or whichever webserver you are using)
- all names and folders are case-sensitive
- look, if you haven't any trailing spaces in none of your filenames (like "PizzyCat " with a space at the end or such)
- check if you really uploaded all your files to the webserver

Comment: I know that but it doesn't help, and it doesn't work

Comment: Turns out that everything was right, but the "hitbox" for the link was very very little , I will work around on getting it right

Answer (score 0):

from your code posted, most likely your href's have a wrong relative path

run your page, and assuming you're using a modern browser, press F12 an examine the link elements to see if the paths make any sense based on your site root.

Comment: You know that is not an answer infact it is a comment.

Comment: I can't disagree with you both, unless of course this is the answer, which based on the OP's original phrasing of the question, it likely is.  Vague questions beget vague answers. I'll be happy to pull my response when the answer is selected.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the path as shown below:

```
<a href="C:\Users\Toni Moni\Downloads\fol.html" target="_blank"><img src="images/slide3/PizzaCat.png" data-stellar-ratio="1.8" data-stellar-vertical-offset="-35" alt=""></a>
```

Comment: but the file should be viewable online from any PC, not only when I am showing it in class.